# How to make count with linq ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I´m trying to make this sql request

```
SELECT number, COUNT(number)
FROM Bet GROUP BY number ORDER BY COUNT(number) DESC;
```

Code

```
public static List<Apuesta> GetAllNumbers(ApplicationDbContext db)
{
    List<Bet> bets = (from b in db.Bet select b.Number).Count();

    return bets;
}
```

and i want to use it in one function using linq.

Comment: Show us what you've already tried yourself...

Comment: You assign an int (from the `Count`) to a `List<Bet>`. Do you want a list that contains the number of `Number` in each `Bet`? (so a `List<int>`)

Comment: Yes, im trying to do that! But it says that you cant convert int - Bet list

Comment: `List<int> bets = (from b in db.Bet select b.Number.Count()).ToList();` should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the result you are trying to achieve you can project your query to an [anonymous type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx):

```
var bets =db.Bet.GroupBy(b=>b.Number)
                .Select(g=>new {Number=g.Key, Count=g.Count()})
                .OrderByDescending(e=>e.Number);
```

Or a [DTO](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-5):

```
public class BetDTO
{
 public int Number{get;set;}
 public int Count{get;set;}
}
```

Then project your result using that custom class:

```
 var bets =db.Bet.GroupBy(b=>b.Number)
             .Select(g=>new BetDTO{Number=g.Key, Count=g.Count()})
             .OrderByDescending(e=>e.Number)
             .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but now I need to plus the amount of the numbers, for example, I have the number 50 two times, but each one with a different amount. So, I dont have the idea how to do that. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: I add amount in BetDTO and in the cusmtom class i use  Amount = ap.Sum() and it works, thanks a lot octavioccl!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @octavioccl. If you like SQL-like LINQ-expressions you can use that snippet:

```
var bets = from b in bets group b by b.Number into g orderby -g.Key  select new { Number = g.Key, Count = g.Count() });
```